# Implementing Pub/Sub or SignalR functionality on .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

Using **SignalR**, it is pretty easy to synchronise, distinct client PC browsers in realtime with inbuilt PUB/SUB mechanism. However SignalR can only be used with .NET 4.0 or above. We are trying to achieve similar functionality in .NET 3.5, since we can't upgrade our application at this point of time.

Considering the fact that SignalR leverages following recent technologies -

1. Task Parallel Library in dot net 4.0
2. WebSockets in HTML5
3. Asynchronous postbacks using AJAX

For asynchronous calls we're planning to use classical BeginAsync and callback approach, & ThreadPool for creting multiple threads. Still learning how to use HTML 5 WebSocket.

We're evaluating other alternatives as well like using jQuery AJAX & writing custom IIS Hander which could take async updates from Client 1 & push this to Client 2 and so on.

If you have done something similar in past, Can you please suggest which approach would be correct to proceed with ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you just need the client part of SignalR in .NET 3.5, you can use the currently released version as it is supported. In my opinion, writing a separate server-side application in .NET4 using SignalR would save you from a lot of trouble. Getting scaleout, message buffering, reconnection logic, etc. right is no simple task and SignalR solves all of this already.

Comment: see this post on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369740/how-to-use-signalr-with-net-3-5

Comment: The TPL has been ported to .NET 3.5: http://nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary

Answer (score 2):

I backported the v1.x and v2.x SignalR clients to NET35. They are available as NuGet packages here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nivot.SignalR.Client.Net35/

Answer (score 0):

You can use node.js and combine with a mvc proyect in .net

on hybrid application

http://sweettam.blogspot.mx/2012/06/hybrid-application-using-aspnet-mvc3.html

Good Luck.