# SignalR implementation in 3.5 asp based project

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

How can I integrate the SignalR references and Dlls into a 3.5 project ?

Comment: i've tried this :PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client  but it's not working in a 3.5 project

Comment: Here is the answer to your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369740/how-to-use-signalr-with-net-3-5/10550691#10550691

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

- you don't use it
- you upgrade your project to a more recent framework (presumably 4.5)
- you do the work to make SignalR work on .NET 3.5, possibly submitting a pull request

The web world moves rapidly; .NET 3.5 was released in November 2007 - over 5 years ago. Forcing all library authors to restrict themselves to this, when the vast majority of projects are going to be for 4.0 / 4.5 is prohibitive. Some projects may choose to do this, some may some may offer a restricted subset of features on older platforms, and some may elect that it simply isn't worth the overhead to support (a lot of effort, to support a marginal and declining user base).

Frankly, I think you should treat this as a reason to consider upgrading framework.

In particular, I can imagine SignalR wanting to make use of the `WebSocket` and improved async IO features, the MVC hooks, plus the http-context stubbing features (for unit tests). But possibly a lot more (I haven't checked).

Comment: you don't use it -> What is an alternative here ?

Comment: @Murali that depends quite a bit on what the OP is doing; polling could be a simple fallback; we wrote our own web-socket server from scratch, but that leaned heavily on the new async socket IO APIs.

Comment: my project is inside a team foundation server and recently we had a major problem the we.config has been locked by our college and he mistakenly changed his pc name inside our network and we can't now unlock the web.config so we are stick in a 3.5 project and we can't manage to upgrade it so  how should i make signalR work in a 3.5 project ?

Comment: We don't support or want to support .NET 3.5 (so don't bother sending a pull request). If you only care about the client working on .NET 3.5 then you can easily make that work by forking the code and using a portable implementation of the TPL for .NET 3.5. If you're talking about the server side, I'd give up and use something else like Marc said.

Comment: @MarcGravell, Great, I do see your web socket implementation in SOF Inbox, Auto Update & in many places. I would like to learn those WebSockets and new async socket. Could you please provide some help link in this post? That could be helpful to a people