# How to do HTTP 1.1 long polling in .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, long-polling, http-1.1, wcf-http

We have a server written in other technology (not .NET) which supports push technology (basically, can withstand long polling via HTTP 1.1) on the web. We are creating a .NET 3.5 application which is supposed to get push notifications (like a chat) from server when certain event occurs.

Is there any .NET framework for .NET 3.5 or below which works as a client for a HTTP 1.1 pushing?
It should support reconnect on getting a message as far as I understand as well as reconnect every two minutes. Can WCF solve this type of tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF does support HTTP 1.1 and there is an async way of receiving notifications described with example [here](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/banderton/2010/07/30/simple-long-polling-wcf-server).

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is a great platform for various implementations of WebRTC.  It starts with WebSockets, falls back through server-sent events, through comet, long polling, and I think it may even fall into flash.  It does so automatically as client and server negotiate to find a match.  SignalR is primarily designed for .net 4+, but [How to use SignalR with .net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369740/how-to-use-signalr-with-net-3-5) has a fork for .net 3.5 which looks promising.